# How to set stoploss in pine-script?

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to plot the stop-losses when I enter a position. The problem is when I enter a position I get 2 stop-losses, but I only want one.

```js
    //@version=4
    strategy("Turtle Project",overlay= true)
    entry_long_2  =  input(55,   title="entry_long_2_input" ,minval=2)                
    profit_long_2 =  input(20,   title="profit_long_2_input",minval=1)                

    cond_L_2 = float(na)                                                             
    cond_L_2:= if high[entry_long_2] >= highest(high,entry_long_2)                   
        high[entry_long_2]                                                            
    else                                                                              
        cond_L_2[1]                                                                   


    cond_L_P_2 = float(na)                                                            
    cond_L_P_2:= if low[profit_long_2] <= lowest(low,profit_long_2)                   
        low[profit_long_2]                                                            
    else                                                                            
        cond_L_P_2[1]                      



    if high < cond_L_2
        strategy.entry("enter long",strategy.long, stop=cond_L_2)

    sl_inp_1 = input(2.0, title='Stop Loss_1 %', type=input.float)/100
    stop_level_1 = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - sl_inp_1)
    stop_1 = max(cond_L_P_2,stop_level_1)

    strategy.exit("exit ","enter long",stop=stop_1)
    plot(stop_level_1,style=plot.style_circles,color=color.red)
    plot(cond_L_2)
    plot(cond_L_P_2, color=color.green)

    entry_long_1 =  input(20,   title="entry_long_2_input" ,minval=2)                
    profit_long_1 =  input(10,   title="profit_long_2_input",minval=1)                

    cond_L_1 = float(na)                                                             
    cond_L_1:= if high[entry_long_1] >= highest(high,entry_long_1)                   
        high[entry_long_1]                                                            
    else                                                                              
        cond_L_1[1]                                                                   


    cond_L_P_1 = float(na)                                                            
    cond_L_P_1:= if low[profit_long_1] <= lowest(low,profit_long_1)                   
        low[profit_long_1]                                                            
    else                                                                            
        cond_L_P_1[1]                      


    if high < cond_L_1
        strategy.entry("enter longj",strategy.long, stop=cond_L_1)

    sl_inp_2 = input(10.0, title='Stop Loss_2 %', type=input.float)/100
    stop_level_2 = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - sl_inp_2)
    stop_2 = max(cond_L_P_1,stop_level_2)

    strategy.exit("exit ","enter longj",stop=stop_2)
    plot(stop_level_2,style=plot.style_circles,color=color.red)
    plot(cond_L_1)
    plot(cond_L_P_1, color=color.green)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlBu3.png)

As you can see in the picture, if I enter with one entry, but there are 2 stop losses? How can I fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The plots have been cleaned up in this code—hopefully like you wanted. See comments to understand the changes that were made. Your trade's stop is now the larger pale red dot.

```
//@version=4
strategy("Turtle Project",overlay= true)
entry_long_2  =  input(55,   title="entry_long_2_input" ,minval=2)                
profit_long_2 =  input(20,   title="profit_long_2_input",minval=1)                

cond_L_2 = float(na)                                                             
cond_L_2:= if high[entry_long_2] >= highest(high,entry_long_2)                   
    high[entry_long_2]                                                            
else                                                                              
    cond_L_2[1]                                                                   


cond_L_P_2 = float(na)                                                            
cond_L_P_2:= if low[profit_long_2] <= lowest(low,profit_long_2)                   
    low[profit_long_2]                                                            
else                                                                            
    cond_L_P_2[1]                      



if high < cond_L_2
    strategy.entry("enter long",strategy.long, stop=cond_L_2)
// For debugging: Shows when your entry order issuing condition is true, but not necessarily when the order is executed.
// plotchar(high < cond_L_2, "high < cond_L_2", "▲", location.top)

sl_inp_1 = input(2.0, title='Stop Loss_1 %', type=input.float)/100
stop_level_1 = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - sl_inp_1)
stop_1 = max(cond_L_P_2,stop_level_1)

strategy.exit("exit ","enter long",stop=stop_1)
// Commented this plot out as it's not useful on the chart.
// plot(stop_level_1, "stop_level_1", style=plot.style_circles,color=color.red)
plot(cond_L_2, "cond_L_2")
plot(cond_L_P_2, "cond_L_P_2", color=color.green)

entry_long_1 =  input(20,   title="entry_long_2_input" ,minval=2)                
profit_long_1 =  input(10,   title="profit_long_2_input",minval=1)                

cond_L_1 = float(na)                                                             
cond_L_1:= if high[entry_long_1] >= highest(high,entry_long_1)                   
    high[entry_long_1]                                                            
else                                                                              
    cond_L_1[1]                                                                   


cond_L_P_1 = float(na)                                                            
cond_L_P_1:= if low[profit_long_1] <= lowest(low,profit_long_1)                   
    low[profit_long_1]                                                            
else                                                                            
    cond_L_P_1[1]                      



if high < cond_L_1
    strategy.entry("enter longj",strategy.long, stop=cond_L_1)

sl_inp_2 = input(10.0, title='Stop Loss_2 %', type=input.float)/100
stop_level_2 = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - sl_inp_2)
stop_2 = max(cond_L_P_1,stop_level_2)

strategy.exit("exit ","enter longj",stop=stop_2)
// This plots the actual stop used in your exit order.
plot(stop_2, "stop_2", style=plot.style_circles, color=color.maroon, linewidth = 3, transp = 80)
// Comment this line out if you don't want the initial entry's stop level to plot.
plot(stop_level_2, "stop_level_2", style=plot.style_circles,color=color.maroon)
plot(cond_L_1, "cond_L_1")
plot(cond_L_P_1, "cond_L_P_1", color=color.green)
```

[image]

Comment: It does not seem like the 2 differend entry´s have differend stoplosses.

Comment: Thx for your help but i dont think its fixed yet

Comment: You only have one entry and one exit in your strategy. You said you had 2 stops when you entered a position and wanted only one. Now you're saying you have 2 different entries and they require different stop losses. I have no idea what you mean, and so cannot help.

Comment: I am  sorry i think i just havent been clear 
enough. Oke let me explain. I have strategy,entry 1 that buys at the 55 day line and i have strategy.entry 2 that buys at the 20 day line. i want to have only one stoploss at eacht entry signal, But i want to be able to see them.So when i enter  i only want to see one of the stoplosses that is linkt to that strategy.entry.

Comment: <img src="https://www.tradingview.com/x/IbBBaXLu/" alt="IbBBaXLu (1274×602)"/>

Comment: plot(stop_level_1, "stop_level_1", style=plot.style_circles,color=color.red) i did enable this one else you only se one stop loss when you have 2 stoplosses

Comment: Perhaps you could set a conditional like `SL_already_set=True`, when you have made your first entry, and skip showing the second?